# Why am I getting "Manifest merger failed" after adding Firebase Storage to my build.gradle?

Tags: android, firebase, android-manifest

I have been using Firebase in my Android project. Specifically: `Firebase Firestore`, `Firebase Authentication`, and `Firebase Cloud Messaging`.

Today I decided to add `Firebase Storage` to my `build.gradle` as I needed the storage features. Now I'm getting an error when building the project:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-214:19 to override.
```

Here's my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.1.1' // this seems to be causing the error
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
    implementation 'de.siegmar:fastcsv:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I tried adding `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` to the `<application>` tag in my Manifest as the error suggested but adding it didn't fix the error.

I also like to note that only the `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.1.1'` dependency in my gradle is on the latest version(as of this writing).

Below Firebase dependencies are not on the latest version:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
```

I've already tried updating the dependencies above to the latest version and building but I still get the same `Manifest merger failed` error.

Anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Migrate to AndroidX. Here is one of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57189639/9968399)

Comment: Quick point: you should be declaring variables for common dependencies version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to migrate to `AndroidX`. The version of `firebase-storage` that you are using requires `AndroidX` to work correctly, from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android):

> This release is a MAJOR version update and includes breaking changes.
>   With this release, libraries are migrated from the Android Support Libraries to the Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries.
>   The updated libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:
>
> 1. Upgrade `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to `v3.2.1` or later.
> 2. Upgrade compileSdkVersion to 28 or later.
> 3. Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX); follow the instructions in [Migrating to AndroidX.](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Also check the following link to know how to migrate:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 1):

They are two way to resolve this issue.

First:
1)Migrate the project in AndroidX.

Two:
1)Downgrade the fire-base dependency.

From this:-

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'